# Can list cast correctly in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, casting, kotlin-android-extensions

I am new to Kotlin,

```
data class RewardDetail(
    val name: String
    val isActivated: Boolean
    val amountInCents: Int?
    val Campain: String?
    val expirationDate: Long?

)

class Rewards(Array<Reward>)

class Reward(
    val name: String     
    isActive: Boolean     
    amountInCents: Int
    campaignId: String
    expirationDate: LocalDateTime
)


val details : List<RewardDetail> = blablabla
val rewards = Rewards(details)
```

can `details` cast to `rewards` successfully?

Also note `campaignId` and `Campain` field name are different in `RewardDetail` and `Reward` and some fields can be nullable in `RewardsDetail`

What is the best way to handle situation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin is strongly-typed. You can never successfully cast one thing into a different class. You can only cast an object into a type that it already satisfies. For example, if you have an Int that is currently only known to the compiler to be a Number, you can cast to Int to tell the compiler that it has an Int, so the compiler will allow you to use the functions that are specific to Int. But nothing but an Int can ever be cast to an Int.

So, unlike weakly typed languages, casting does not convert from one type to another. Casting is only you making a promise to the compiler that an object *already is* of the other type.

In your example, the only way to get a RewardDetail from a Reward is by writing a function that manually converts each property to the appropriate type.

The Rewards class above is largely redundant. There's no need for a wrapper class around a single Array or List unless you need to do validation of items added to or retrieved from the list. In that case, it would probably make more sense to create a subclass of ArrayList for that purpose, so you could still easily iterate the list and use all the List and Iterable helper functions on it.

Probably about 95% of the time, you should prefer using List over using Array. Arrays should be used only when you need a fixed size collection that is also mutable, or if you are working with highly performance-critical code. The reason it should be limited to these uses is that mutability should be avoided when possible for robustness and Arrays are more cumbersome to work with than MutableLists.

A typical implementation of a function that converts from one type to another would be to write an extension function `RewardDetail.toReward()` extension function, or a `toReward()` function inside the RewardDetail class. However, in your case you need to decide what you need to happen when some of the values of RewardDetail are null. Maybe you just return `null` so your conversion function should be `toRewardOrNull()`, or you provide default values for the properties that have no value in RewardDetail.